# React Native - Change Header's backgroundColor

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mobile, header

[screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1TFU.png)

And I want to know how can I change the white header's color to black?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for navigation on the react native app.

Here's a demo code block to configure header background.

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{ title: 'Demo', headerStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#000000'
           } }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```